# Best practise to use code on every page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-notification, laravel-5.8

I'm looking for the best practise to implement user notifications in "app.blade.php" layout.

The Layout should always check for user notifications and I don't want to implement in every Controller.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you don’t mean [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) and your own implementation, then you’d want to use a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers):

Create a composer called `UserNotificationComposer` or similar, add your logic to that, then create a `ViewServiceProvider` and link them up:

```
View::composer(
    '*', 'App\Http\View\Composers\UserNotificationComposer'
);
```

(This is asuming you’re using your own ‘user notifications’, if you’re using the Larvel Notifications, then you don’t need any logic in your controllers.)

Comment: I did it in this way

`/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.app', function($view){
            $view->with('userNotification', UserNotifications::getNotifications());
        });
    }`